# How to set focus on child window when pointer-event is none in parent. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Child window is not getting focused, when clicked on parent window. Just because of pointer-event. Without pointer-event it gets focused on child window. But I dont want the pointer enabled on parent window while child window is open. But on click it should take the focus to child window. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

```
returnval = window.open(qsUrl, args,"scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes,width=400, height=300");
document.getElementById('focs').value="1";
document.getElementById("focs").style.pointerEvents="none";

function Disable_Parent(event)
    {
        if(returnval && !returnval.closed)
        {
            if(getBrowser()=="IE" && detectIE()<10)
            {
                event.keyCode=0;
            }
            else
            {
                event.which=0;
                event.preventDefault(true);
                event.stopPropagation(true);
            }
            returnval.focus();
        }
    }
    function Child_Close()
    {
        var ChildWindow=document.getElementById("focs").value;
        if(ChildWindow==1)
        {
            document.getElementById('focs').value="0";
            returnval.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can do one thing here add transparent background to the child window which is a block element and cover all the screen and on it, you can place a small window which acts as your child and it won't focus on the back parent window while pointing...

Comment: Yes, what you said is right. But for some clarifications, parent window has to be shown. That is why I'm opening the child window. But there shouldn't be any access in parent window when child is open. Your idea was good. This may help me in future Thank you.

Comment: Yes, for parent window I said the background should be transparent and inside of it, there should be a small window which seems like only a small window is there. (like bootstrap modal)

Comment: I think use some overlay with pointer-events none behind the child element, just like modal r dialog do

Comment: @FirozTennali Overlay seems really cool, but the child window is getting accessed by two other parent windows. Could you please tell me how to call the child window page in overlay mode. Without writing the code on the same page. Child window got so many functions and according to parent window it acts. I'm totally new to this concept. Actually I was doing back end before. So I didn't get any idea on this. And model also looks good like overlay.

Comment: @Awais Model seems good. But I have to access this model from another jsp page, which acts as child for 2 parent jsp. Is it posible to call the child as model to parent jsp?

Comment: @FirozTennali I did as you said, but in model. I didnt get an idea to do it in overlay. But it worlks. Problems have been mentioned in this post. Could you please help me https://stackoverflow.com/q/59509856/11962586. Thank you.

Comment: @Awais I did as you said. But I cant bring that in same page. The problem is specified in this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/59509856/11962586. Could you p[lease help me. Thank you.